# Textbox value to array or list

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I enter the value in textbox: 
*1,2,3,4,5,6,7...*

How to into to int array or list  and show value display ??? 
And stop when a user enters the wrong consecutive 3 times or total error of 5

Comment: Can you post what code you have tried?

Comment: What do you mean by _the wrong_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        //textbox is your textbox controls' name
        string[] content = textbox.Text.Split(',');
        //use linq convert stringp[] to int[]
        int[] nums = (from num in content
                      select int.Parse(num)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the last part of your question (the bit about stopping when a user enters something wrong... I guess you'd have to define "wrong" in this context). Regardless, the following code should take values entered into a text box (let's call it txtNumbers) and put it in an array of ints.

```
string[] splitContent = txtNumbers.Text.Split(new char[] { ',' });
int[] nums = new int[splitContent.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < splitContent.Length; i++)
{
    nums[i] = Int32.Parse(splitContent[i]);
}
```

Comment: I entered into the textbox, enter a value of 3 times wrong, the program will stop or enter an incorrect total is 5 then stop program. Thanks you.